# Is it a good practice to bind an Android Service to AndroidViewModel?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-service-binding, android-viewmodel

Below is my example Client and AndroidViewModel implementation. Assuming all the binding and un-binding is taken care of, is this a good way to talk to a bound service from an AndroidViewModel?

```
class ServiceViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){

    private var serviceClient = ServiceClient(application)

    override fun onCleared() {
        serviceClient.close()
        println("cleared view model")
    }

    fun talkToService(){
        serviceClient.executeSomeMethod()
    }

}
```

---

```
class ServiceClient(private val context: Context) : ServiceConnection, AutoCloseable {

    init {
        bindService()
    }

    override fun close() {
        unbindService()
    }

    //..onServiceConnected gives IBinder
    //..onServiceDisconnected notifies


    fun executeSomeMethod(){
        binder.executeSomeServiceMethod()
    }


}
```

Comment: bound service is like a normal data repository - treat it as any other data model